# xpath find location in document

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-parsing

Trying to find the value of "aging-timer" in the following XML document:

```
<ospf3-database-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/11.1R2/junos-routing">
    <ospf3-database external-heading="OSPF3">
        <lsa-type>Extern</lsa-type>
        <lsa-id>0.0.0.1</lsa-id>
        <advertising-router>172.27.255.6</advertising-router>
        <sequence-number>0x80000001</sequence-number>
        <age>1792</age>
        <checksum>0x90bd</checksum>
        <lsa-length>28</lsa-length>
        <ospf3-external-lsa>
            <ospf3-prefix>::/0</ospf3-prefix>
            <ospf3-prefix-options>0x0</ospf3-prefix-options>
            <type-value>1</type-value>
            <metric>0</metric>
        </ospf3-external-lsa>
        <ospf-database-extensive>
            <aging-timer junos:seconds="1808">
                00:30:08
            </aging-timer>
            <installation-time junos:seconds="1790">
                00:29:50
            </installation-time>
            <expiration-time junos:seconds="1808">
                00:30:08
            </expiration-time>
            <send-time junos:seconds="1790">
                00:29:50
            </send-time>
            <lsa-changed-time junos:seconds="1790">
                00:29:50
            </lsa-changed-time>
            <lsa-change-count>1</lsa-change-count>
        </ospf-database-extensive>
    </ospf3-database>
</ospf3-database-information>
```

The only caveat is that I only want it if "ospf3-prefix" has a text of ::/0.
I am trying this xpath:

```
//x:ospf3-external-lsa[x:ospf3-prefix=\"::/0\"]/ancestor::x:ospf3-database/x:ospf-database-extensive/x:aging-timer
```

using the x to handle namespaces in perl:

```
   my $xdatav6 = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $defv6);
   my $dataxv6 = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xdatav6);
   $dataxv6->registerNs("x", "http://xml.juniper.net/junos/11.1R2/junos-routing");
```

but this doesn't work, it seems that when I use the ancestor it can grab everything except anything under the "ospf-database-extensive" tree.

Comment: trying to find the value of what?

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit. Value of aging-timer.

Comment: I don't see anyhting obviously wrong - you sort of imply that you've done some debugging -- specifically you're sure that: (1) //x:ospf3-external-lsa[x:ospf3-prefix=\"::/0\"] is selecting the correct nodes; and (2) the ancestor::x:ospf3-database selects the correct node but (3) it then fails to find the child ospf-database-extensive node?

Comment: Yes, if I have the following path: "//x:ospf3-external-lsa[x:ospf3-prefix=\"::/0\"]/ancestor::x:ospf3-database/x:ospf3-external-lsa/x:type-value", it correctly prints 1

Comment: Okay just ran this again, and it appears that I am not getting the entire response in the document.

Comment: it was a PEBKAC. The path was correct the entire time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML you show isn't valid as it doesn't have a URI for the `junos` namespace that is used in `junos:seconds`. I changed the root tag to read

```
xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/11.1R2/junos-routing"
```

to get things working.

This is the longest XPath expression I've seen, but this does the trick! Put the appropriate namespace prefixes in as needed.

```
/ospf3-database-information/ospf3-database[ospf3-external-lsa/ospf3-prefix="::/0"]/ospf-database-extensive/aging-timer
```